# Set Duplicity to do not follow symbolic links

Tags: command-line, backup, symbolic-link, duplicity

> Currently duplicity supports (...) symbolic links (...) but not hard links.

http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/duplicity.1.html

It is not clarified but most likely it means that soft links are followed. For obvious reasons I want to avoid backuping `~/Desktop/temporary_symbolic_link_to_hard_drive_with_gbs_of_data` and [other symbolic-link related problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/753391/how-can-i-check-why-diff-command-failed).

How can I disable following symbolic links by duplicity (like `--no-dereference` option in diff command)?

I know that I can use `--exclude` option but it requires generating backup command by script detecting symbolic links but it would be overcomplicated and fragile.

Comment: I think that "supports symbolic links" means "symbolic links are backed up", not "symbolic links are followed" (which would be really strange, in my opinion)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini - seems that you are right ( http://superuser.com/questions/483442/including-files-in-a-symlink-directory-when-backing-up-with-duplicity ). I will accept the first answer linking to official documentation confirming this. "which would be really strange, in my opinion" - I agree, but my problem with diff was caused by unexpected following symlinks (http://askubuntu.com/questions/753391/how-can-i-check-why-diff-command-failed), so I wanted to be sure before backup will be needed.

Comment: You can answer your own question. You are the person who did the research :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duplicity now supports this (in version v0.7.11 and up) via the `--copy-links` option. See the [duplicity man page](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html).

Note that this a later version of duplicity than standard Ubuntu trusty or xenial packages. You need to install duplicity from upstream e.g. `ppa:duplicity-team/ppa`